# Use regexp in bash to obtain substring of string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a string like follows:

```
my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34
```

I'd like to use a regular expression to capture all text before the first instance of -[0-9] so in this case I would get:

```
my-name-is-yes
```

I'm going to be porting this to ansible so it must use regexp and not sed or awk or something like that.

I've used sed to come up with something, but again, I need regexp:

```
echo $x | rev |cut -d. -f6 | rev | sed -e 's/-[0-9]*$//g'
my-name-is-yes
```

Issue here is there may be more periods than . 6 that I would need to cut on.

Comment: And where are you stuck? Please show the script that fails.

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. Please show your code and state where you are having trouble. Also see [Strange and maddening rules](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/) and [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289).

Comment: Apparently you can't do this in bash. Was said 2 days ago bash doesn't support lazy quantifiers. I guess you'd have to use a different shell...

Comment: A basic regex and `sed` will do, e.g. `sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]*.*$//'` (note you need both `[0-9][0-9]*` as `'*'` will match *zero or more* occurrences). You can simply `echo "my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34" | sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]*.*$//'` to obtain your desired results.

Comment: @sln, you can do this is bash *much easier* with a simple *parameter expansion*. If the full string is stored in the variable `a`, then, e.g. `echo ${a%%-[0-9]*}` is all you need.

Comment: The problem with any type parameter expansion is the *"I'm going to be porting this to ansible so it must use regexp"* part. If ansible has them, you are fine, otherwise a regex will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that can extract our desired output here would be as simple as:

```
([A-Za-z-]+)(-[0-9].+)
```

and our desired data is in this capturing group: `([A-Za-z-]+)`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP27Yq/1/)

#### Advice

[user3299633](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3299633/user3299633) has much simplified that with this solution:

> ```
> if [[ $x =~ ([[:alnum:]-]+)(-[[:digit:]].+) ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
> ```

Comment: Any idea why this won't return anything on bash? if [[ $x =~ (.+?)(-[0-9].+) ]]; then echo $BASH_REMATCH[1]; fi

Comment: `+?` (non-greedy) is not supported by Bash regex.

Comment: Emma, your last regex worked. Please update your answer and I will give you credit.

Comment: Thanks, shortened it a bit to if [[ $x =~ ([[:alnum:]-]+)(-[[:digit:]].+) ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi but your way works perfectly and is the answer I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ str='my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34'
$ echo "${str%%-[[:digit:]]*}"
my-name-is-yes
```

where `${parameter%%word}` removes the longes match of the pattern to which *`word`* expands from the end of the expansion of *`parameter`*.

Comment: I like it, but "I'm going to be porting this to ansible so it must use regexp", and I don't know if ansible can do this. No dings, but something you might want to address `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As far as I know, ansible can run shell commands, and since OP seems to look for a solution involving the `=~` Bash operator, I assume they can also use parameter expansion instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell paramater expansion to solve you stated test case. Here's an example:

```
# var=my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34
# echo ${var%%\-[0-9]*}
my-name-is-yes
```

If you need this is variable, you can assign the expansion instead, ie

```
var=my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34
var2=${var%%\-[0-9]*}
echo $var2
my-name-is-yes
```

You can even overwrite your first value with the expansion value,

```
var=my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34
var=${var%%\-[0-9]*}
echo $var
my-name-is-yes
```

The `%` and `%%` parameter expansion operators mean "remove matching value from right side of the variable" while `%%` means remove the maximum matching from from the right.

There are also the `#` and `##` parameter expansion operators, which perform similar function, but "removing matching values from the left side of the variable's value.
IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
s='my-name-is-yes-111111.maybe.text.here?-34.34.34'
regex='^([A-Za-z0-9-]*)-[0-9]'
if [[  "$s" =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
else
  echo "No match!";
fi;
```

Output: `my-name-is-yes`.

See the [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/22yskU) and the [regex grpah](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5BA-Za-z0-9-%5D*)-%5B0-9%5D):

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `([A-Za-z0-9-]*)` - Capturing group #1 (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will have this value): 0 or more ASCII letters, digits or `-` chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]` - a digit.

Comment: First instance of `-[0-9]`. Your regex matches the _last_ instance

Comment: @sln See https://ideone.com/22yskU - the result is as expected. It is a bit more portable version of the [regex  that works for OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605222/use-regexp-in-bash-to-obtain-substring-of-string/56605606?noredirect=1#comment99787273_56605320).

Comment: I'm saying your regex has the _potential_ to match the _last instance_ `is-ye-2s-1` which should _not_ be expected.

Comment: The question is _why_ you have `0-9` and `-` in the same greedy class ? It would be better if it was at least non-greedy `*?`

Comment: @sln `*?` does not work in Bash. I used what I used because that is what works for OP.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot, bash sucks because it's greedy. Then you have no alternative then to get rid of the [A-Za-z`0-9`-]. the part that could be real trouble. But that would almost be @Emma's regex.